# rack-attack isn't filtering blacklisted referers

Tags: heroku, spam, referrer-spam, rackattack

I have set up the rack-attack config per the advanced configuration instructions. I am using Heroku and have confirmed the env variable contains all of the urls and everything is properly formatted.

I have even gone into the console on Heroku and run the following:

```
req = Rack::Attack::Request.new({'HTTP_REFERER' => '4webmasters.org'})
```

and then tested with:

```
Rack::Attack.blacklisted?(req)
```

to which I get:

```
=> true
```

but in my analytics on google the referrals are filled with every url on my list. What am I missing?

My config includes this pretty standard block:

```
# Split on a comma with 0 or more spaces after it.
# E.g. ENV['HEROKU_VARIABLE'] = "foo.com, bar.com"
# spammers = ["foo.com", "bar.com"]
spammers = ENV['HEROKU_VARIABLE'].split(/,\s*/)
#
# Turn spammers array into a regexp
spammer_regexp = Regexp.union(spammers) # /foo\.com|bar\.com/
blacklist("block referer spam") do |request|
 request.referer =~ spammer_regexp
end
#
```

HEROKU_VARIABLE =>

```
"ertelecom.ru, 16clouds.com, bee.lt, belgacom.be, virtua.com.br, nodecluster.net, telesp.net.br, belgacom.be, veloxzone.com.br, baidu.com, floating-share-buttons.com, 4webmasters.org, trafficmonetizer.org, webmonetizer.net, success-seo.com, buttons-for-website.com, videos-for-your-business.com, Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com, 100dollars-seo.com, e-buyeasy.com, free-social-buttons.com, traffic2money.com, erot.co, success-seo.com, semalt.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of referrers are Google Analytic spam referrers. They never actually hit your website so blocking them with rack-attack is pointless. The data you see from them in GA is all fake. To stop this in your GA, set up a filter to ignore visits from that referrer.